What does Nvidia Geforce Experience's 'Optimise' button optimise for?
In the Nvidia GeForce Experience app, there’s a section in each game you own where there’s an Optimise button (not sure if it’s actually called that).
What does it optimise for?

From the GeForce Experience website (my emphasis):

GeForce Experience takes the hassle out of PC gaming by configuring your game’s graphics settings for you. Don’t know what texture filtering level to set in Overwatch? Not to worry. NVIDIA taps into the power of the NVIDIA cloud data center to test thousands of PC hardware configurations and find the best balance of performance and image quality. Then it automatically configures personalised graphics settings based on your PC’s GPU, CPU, and display.

So it optimised for performance based on your PC's hardware.
"The best balance of performance and image quality" is of course a subjective matter, and the goal of the optimisation may not at all align with yours.
More importantly, this won't always actually optimise your game. See for example this Reddit thread, in which the author points out GE makes some remarkable changes to the graphics settings.
From the reactions:

often it does stuff you don't want to have (like rendering a game at higher resolution and downsampling for higher texture quality at the cost of high fps). You should always review the suggested settings and use your own judgment.

And:

one would assume it would take into consideration the articles that Nvidia post up with their tweaking guides. I.e. there isn't much difference between High and Ultra shadows, so set it to High, as it will save you 5 fps, etc. etc. But it doesn't seem to even do that.

This is the top of the iceberg, coming from the first results of my search, but is completely consistent with my own very long experience (I never use the optimization anymore) and the feedback I encountered online throughout the years.
But it doesn't hurt to try the 'Opimize' option, take note of the changes, and see if there's something that's improving your gameplay or experience. It might help.

One thing that the current other answer didn't mention is that it's possible to customize the optimisation feature to prioritize either higher performance or higher quality by clicking the wrench icon next to the Optimize button, as shown below in this screenshot:

This option also allows you to select a resolution. Note that Nvidia does not specify which settings are being changed based on the bar.
As an aside, this is how it looks in the upcoming Nvidia App, which is currently in Open Beta and rumored to officially be released at CES 2025 alongside the announcement of the RTX 50 series:


Everything here is good except about the rumor. Nvidia officially says, "we intend to migrate all remaining GeForce Experience users to the new NVIDIA app when it exits beta before the end of the year.". https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/news/nvidia-app-beta-update-g-sync-controls-rtx-hdr-multi-monitor/

The Nvidia App has been released.
